# Bind textbox to combobox as text

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I am trying to bind the `ComboBox` selected item to a `TextBox`, I have tried:

```
<ComboBox  x:Name="TitlesCombobox"  IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" Text="-- Subtitles --"   >
    <ComboBoxItem Content="sub title 1"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="sub title 2"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="sub title 3"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="sub title 4"/>
</ComboBox>
```

and:

```
<TextBox x:Name="freestyleSubtitleTxt" Text="{Binding ElementName=TitlesCombobox, Path=SelectedValue}" />
```

but when I select item I get in `TextBox`: `System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: sub title 3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind to `SelectedItem.Content`:

```
<TextBox x:Name="freestyleSubtitleTxt" 
         Text="{Binding ElementName=TitlesCombobox, Path=SelectedItem.Content}" />
```

Or replace the `ComboBoxItems` with `strings` and bind to `SelectedItem`:

```
<ComboBox  x:Name="TitlesCombobox"  IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" Text="-- Subtitles --"
           xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <s:String>sub title 1</s:String>
    <s:String>sub title 2</s:String>
    <s:String>sub title 3</s:String>
    <s:String>sub title 4</s:String>
</ComboBox>

<TextBox x:Name="freestyleSubtitleTxt" Text="{Binding ElementName=TitlesCombobox, Path=SelectedItem}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

To bind only to the value of a `ComboBoxItem` use the Property `SelectedValuePath`.

Your `ComboBox` should look like this:

```
<ComboBox  x:Name="TitlesCombobox" 
           IsEditable="True" 
           IsReadOnly="True" 
           Text="-- Subtitles --" 
           SelectedValuePath="Content">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="sub title 1"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="sub title 2"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="sub title 3"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="sub title 4"/>
</ComboBox>
```

The `SelectedValuePath` property specifies the path to the property that is used to determine the value of the `SelectedValue` property.